# Monitoring application/tracking memory

Tags: windows, debugging, memory

I would like to "listen" an application on windows. When i say "listen" i mean that i have an application and i want to monitor some data displayed in it ( so it could be about monitoring the memory of my process and just reading some adress ( similar to what game wizard used to do ). Any other idea is welcome

Thx

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=645) article explains how an application can use the built in windows performance counter system to instrument and view counters that are custom to you application.  As an added bonus you will also be able to monitor the standard counter (memory, etc) that are supported by the OS.